# Select2 4.x.x selectbox tag support

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am trying to recreate select2 tagging feature as seen in the examples.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

```
<select class='equipment' name='equipment' multiple='multiple'>
 <option value='Please Select'>Please Select</option>
 <option value='1'>Laptop</option>
 <option value='2'>Laptop Power Supply</option>
 <option value='3'>2nd Laptop Power Supply</option>
 <option value='4'>Smartphone</option>
</select> 
  <script type='text/x-example-code'>
    $('.equipment').select2({
     tags: true
      })
   </script>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I've tried other things as well but it doesn't seem to be working.
In other selectboxes that I just use select2 to show a searchbox it works fine.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/aoz5krud/ what is the issue?

Comment: It must was a mix up with my code. Thanks for pointing out that it was working as I was going crazy, Thanks @IrvinDominin